# multiplication of C# lists

Tags: c#, multiplication

I am having a brain freeze and just cant figure out a solution to this problem.

I created a class called CustomSet that contained a string list. The class holding a reference to CustomSet stores it as a list.

```
public class CustomSet : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    internal IList<string> elements;

    public CustomSet(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.elements = new List<string>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            return elements;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return elements.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

So what I would like to do is iterate over this list of custom sets to out put a 2d string array where the columns are the number of customSet(s) and the rows are a multiplication of the customSet elements.

As an example, if there were 3 custom sets in the list: 1st had 3 elements, 2nd had 2 elements and 3rd had 3 elements. I would want to output 3 columns and 18 rows (3*2*3). The following code is an attempt at the solution:

```
CustomSet motion = new CustomSet("Motion");
motion.Elements.Add("low");
motion.Elements.Add("medium");
motion.Elements.Add("high");

CustomSet speed = new CustomSet("Speed");
speed.Elements.Add("slow");
speed.Elements.Add("Fast");

CustomSet mass = new CustomSet("Mass");
mass.Elements.Add("light");
mass.Elements.Add("medium");
mass.Elements.Add("heavy");

List<CustomSet> aSet = new List<CustomSet>();
aSet.Add(motion);
aSet.Add(speed);
aSet.Add(mass);

//problem code
int rows = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < aSet.Count; i++)
{
    rows *= aSet[i].Elements.Count;
}

string[,] array = new String[aSet.Count, rows];
int modulus;

for (int i = 0; i < aSet.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        modulus = j % aSet[i].Elements.Count;
        array[i, j] = aSet[i].Elements[modulus];
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < aSet.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(array[i, j] + " / ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
//end

Console.ReadLine();
```

However, the code does not output the correct string array (though it is close). What I would like it to out put is the following:

low / slow / light /

low / slow / medium /

low / slow / heavy /

low / Fast / light /

low / Fast / medium /

low / Fast / heavy /

medium / slow / light /

medium / slow / medium /

medium / slow / heavy /

medium / Fast / light /

medium / Fast / medium /

medium / Fast / heavy /

high / slow / light /

high / slow / medium /

high / slow / heavy /

high / Fast / light /

high / Fast / medium /

high / Fast / heavy /

Now the variables in this problem is the number of customSets in the list and the number of elements in each CustomSet.

Comment: So, you want the cross join / cartesian product of the three lists?

Comment: The three lists are an example. What I want is the cross join / cartesian product of the number of items in the list (the IList<CustomSet> aSet)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the product in one go:

```
var crossJoin = from m in motion
                from s in speed
                from ms in mass
                select new { Motion = m, Speed = s, Mass = ms };

foreach (var val in crossJoin)
{
   Console.Write("{0} / {1} / {2}", val.Motion, val.Speed, val.Mass);
}
```

---

Now, since you don't know the number of lists, you need to do some more. Eric Lippert covers this in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx), where you can use the `CertesianProduct` function defined there in the following manner:

```
var cProduct = SomeContainerClass.CartesianProduct(aSet.Select(m => m.Elements));
var stringsToOutput = cProduct.Select(l => string.Join(" / ", l));
```

Comment: Except that motion/speed/mass are also in a (variable) list.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - yes, but that's more of a result of the current design (which can be improved).

Comment: This solution is not general and only solves a particular example. A recursive method is needed to achieve this.

Comment: @greenbeast did you read my updated answer to the end? The use of `CartesianProduct`? @Tarik

Comment: Sorry oded, I hadn't. Reading now :)

Comment: I don't get the "SomeContainerClass" bit. Does this only contain the CartesianProduct method? and if so how do I implement it (just replace the "T"s with "string"?)

Comment: @greenbeast - Extention methods need to live in a static class, I just  used a fake name, so yes. And you just leave the `T` alone and use the code as is.

Comment: Apologies for the delay (wifey just had a baby boy!). Anyway, did as you said and it all worked (too easy). I was torn between this being the correct answer or Kai Hartmanns (which I think is a more puritan solution). But this solution is more popular and is using the technology that is available in C# (e.g. Linq). So I checked this one as the correct answer

Comment: @greenbeast - congratulations. Now, go get some sleep ;)

Answer (score 1):

This recursive approach shows the results as desired, with a list of n CustomSet objects:

```
void OutputSets(List<CustomSet> aSet, int setIndex, string hirarchyString)
{
    string ouputString = hirarchyString;
    int nextIndex = setIndex + 1;

    foreach (string element in aSet[setIndex].Elements)
    {
        if (nextIndex < aSet.Count)
        {
            OutputSets(aSet, nextIndex, hirarchyString + element + " / ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ouputString + element + " / ");
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with:

```
OutputSets(aSet, 0, "");
```